# Error PRVG-11322 while atempting to install ODAC 12c release 3

Tags: oracle

I have been trying to install the Oracle Developper Tools with ODAC update 3 (because I need it to work with Entity framwork 6) but the Unified installer bring me a PRVG-11322 Error.

[It seem to be linked](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3675832) to the fact that my computer have an underscore in his hostname (and I can't change it, work domain-joined workstation)

Altought the [install instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121021-2389380.html) mention installation using xcopy, I can't find the instruction that are supposed to be in the zip package.

I am pretty much out of ideas. Do you know how to do it.

Comment: I wonder if you could install it to another machine and then copy the installation and relevant registry settings to your machine?

Comment: And tell your company's sys admin(s) that having underscore in hostname components of DNS names is a bad idea (not allowed!)

Answer (score 1):

use the installer in commandline mode and use the option to ignore prerequisite checks

Comment: by using command line, TNSNAMES.ORA will not be built.